# How to integrate laravel packages into an application

Tags: php, laravel, blogs, forum, newsletter

I have just installed Laravel 5.3 and also imported the authentication package which consists of a login and registration pages.

All this works fine, my problem is: I am trying to integrate a blog, forum, newsletter system in this authentication system.

I have been searching  for packages but most I have seen are packages that installed as projects.

But all I want is to integrate this component I have talked about into my existing system.

Comment: You really need to explain what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and search the packages on http://packalyst.com/ or https://packagist.org for packages. You will use `composer require` to pull in the packages. [This package](https://packagist.org/packages/serverfireteam/blog) looks like it might be on the track you want for the blog and [this for the forum](https://packagist.org/packages/riari/laravel-forum).

Those will be the best sources for packages that are not directly integrated in a Laravel project.  You may also want to try a CRUD admin panel such as [Voyager](https://packagist.org/packages/tcg/voyager).

Another great find is building the blog items you need. You can find a great tutorial [here](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-starting-the-admin-area) that also goes over a lot of key Laravel concepts.